# Is there a way to get a <div> in the same line of another <div>?

Tags: html, css

So I have 2 `<div>` tags in my body, and I want them both to be in one line. However, it automatically makes a line break. Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: `div`-elements are block-elements, so they will by default try to take up as much width as possible. you could achieve this with `inline-block`, `grid`, `flexbox` and much more.

Answer (score 3):

```css
.firstDiv {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 30%;
  background-color: grey;
}

.secondDiv {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 30%;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.mainDiv {
  
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv">
<div class="firstDiv">
First Div
</div>
<div class="secondDiv">
Second Div
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using `display: flex` is better than `display: inline-block` as you have better control over things (eg. in responsiveness). I think this should be the correct answer. Although, `.first-div` looks better than `.firstDiv` to me.

Answer (score 2):

Use display inline block

```css
.content {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">Content</div>
<div class="content">Content</div>
```